# The best practice to pass hierrachy category value to functions

Tags: java, c#, c++, visual-studio

I have a tree-structured categories parameter that I want to pass to a function. I hope that it can be friendly enough to the coding assistance like Visual Assist or IntelliSense, and it can directly pop up the current possible options. Currently, the best option I can think of to achieve this is to use an Enum type as a parameter. For example:

```
enum CategoriesTree
{
        ModuleA,
        ModuleA_SubModuleA,
        ModuleA_SubModuleB,
        ModuleA_SubModuleC,
        ModuleA_SubModuleC_ClassA,
        ModuleA_SubModuleC_ClassB,
        ModuleA_SubModuleC_ClassC,
        ModuleA_SubModuleD,
        ModuleB,
        ModuleB_SubModuleA,
        ModuleB_SubModuleB,
        ModuleB_SubModuleC,
}

void MyFunction(CategoriesTree category);
```

In an IDE like Visual Studio, after I type "void MyFunction(", the code assist will directly list all the enumeration types for me to choose from. This achieves half of what I expect. However, the drawback is that it directly gives all the enumerations. In actual situations, there may be thousands of enumerations, so it is not convenient. What I hope for is to give me a hierarchical tree structure level by level, such as starting with two options, **ModuleA** and **ModuleB**, and then when I choose **ModuleA**, press Tab or ".", and then give me the next level of options: **SubModuleA**, **SubModuleB**, **SubModuleC** and **SubModuleD**, and so on.

Therefore, I have come up with another solution:

```
public class category_base
{

};

public class CategoriesTree
{
    public class ModuleA_Def : category_base
    {
        public class SubModuleA_Def : category_base
        {
        };
        public class SubModuleB_Def : category_base
        {
        };
        public class SubModuleC_Def : category_base
        {
            public class ClassA_Def : category_base
            {
            };
            public class ClassB_Def : category_base
            {
            };
            public class ClassC_Def : category_base
            {
            };
            public ClassA_Def ClassA = new ClassA_Def();
            public ClassB_Def ClassB = new ClassB_Def();
            public ClassC_Def ClassC = new ClassC_Def();
        };
        public class SubModuleD_Def : category_base
        {
        };
        public SubModuleA_Def SubModuleA = new SubModuleA_Def();
        public SubModuleB_Def SubModuleB = new SubModuleB_Def();
        public SubModuleC_Def SubModuleC = new SubModuleC_Def();
        public SubModuleD_Def SubModuleD = new SubModuleD_Def();
    };

    public class ModuleB_Def : category_base
    {
        public class SubModuleA_Def : category_base
        {
        };
        public class SubModuleB_Def : category_base
        {
        };
        public class SubModuleC_Def : category_base
        {
        };
        public SubModuleA_Def SubModuleA = new SubModuleA_Def();
        public SubModuleB_Def SubModuleB = new SubModuleB_Def();
        public SubModuleC_Def SubModuleC = new SubModuleC_Def();
    };
    public static ModuleA_Def ModuleA = new ModuleA_Def();
    public static ModuleB_Def ModuleB = new ModuleB_Def();
}
```

Now, I need to call this function:

```
void MyFunction(category_base category);
```

This method can indeed do what the enumeration method cannot do: my entire parameter has been structured into a tree. However, it cannot achieve what the enumeration can do: when I type "void MyFunction(", there is no code prompt popping up. I have to manually enter "CategoriesTree" and add a "." to start.

I would like to ask if there is a solution that can achieve the advantages of both these 2 methods? And the solution should be used in C++, C# and Java, event Typescript.

Comment: Food for thought: I wouldn't soley advise to make such a decision on IDE convenience. So what do you mean to express; if it's just a selection of values I would go with an enum, if you would actually have some logic behind it, the usage of classes might come in handy.

Comment: You couldn't avoid "." when you use class, enum is already a good way to go.